# addObject replaces the previous values

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

In the following code i am trying to add the user selected names in `arrayDoctors`, say `A,B` and then i add it to `selectedDoctors` array. But the 2nd time i select doctors `C,D` and add it to `selectedDoctors` array it replaces the previous objects `A,B` to `C` and `D`.

```
- (void)doneDoctorSelection:(id)sender
{
   [pop3 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   NSString *str = [arrayDoctors objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *str1 = [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" + %d",arrayDoctors.count-1]];

   if([arrayDoctors count] == 1)
    lblDoctor.text = str;
   else
      lblDoctor.text = str1;

   [selectedDoctors addObject:arrayDoctors];
   [selectedDoctorIdList addObject:arrayDoctorsId];

   NSLog(@"selectedDoneDoctors %@ ",selectedDoctors);

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is that array never empty then?  If it is then this will crash: `[arrayDoctors objectAtIndex:0];`.

Comment: may be problem with re-iniatilization of selectedDoctors array once check it.

Comment: `addObject:` does add, not replace. So, either you're removing somewhere else or you misunderstand the log. Do you really mean to add the whole `arrayDoctors` (instead of its contents)?

Comment: The calls to `addObject` look suspect.  Are you sure you don't want `addObjectsFromArray`?

Comment: selectedDoctors is an array of array.

Comment: @Wain.... what do you mean? I didnt get you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this part

```
NSMutableArray *tempDoctor = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayDoctors];

[selectedDoctors addObject:tempDoctor];
```

You can use

```
[selectedDoctors addObject:[arrayDoctors mutableCopy]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah!! finally found the solution. I was removing the objects from arrayDoctors before putting new values in it, and i had initialized it in viewDidLoad method. So what was happening is when i did [selectedDoctors addObject:arrayDoctors]; the second time it was replacing the same object at 1st place also since its uses the same memory location. The solution was to create a temporary object. The following is the changed code.

```
- (void)doneDoctorSelection:(id)sender
{
   [pop3 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   NSString *str = [arrayDoctors objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *str1 = [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" + %d",arrayDoctors.count-1]];

   NSMutableArray *tempDoctor = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayDoctors];
   NSMutableArray *tempDocorId = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:arrayDoctorsId
                               ];

   if([arrayDoctors count] == 1)
       lblDoctor.text = str;
   else
       lblDoctor.text = str1;

   NSLog(@"Before Adding %@ ",selectedDoctors);

   [selectedDoctors addObject:tempDoctor];
   [selectedDoctorIdList addObject:tempDocorId];

   //[selectedDoctors addObjectsFromArray:arrayDoctors];
   //[selectedDoctorIdList addObjectsFromArray:arrayDoctorsId];

   NSLog(@"selectedDoneDoctors %@ ",selectedDoctors);

}
```

Thanx for pointing me in right direction.